Which algorithm is executed by FlowAccumulationFullWorkflow in Whitebox Tools?
Whitebox Toolset for Hyrdological Analysis offers many different flow accumulation algorithms, like D8, DInf, MdInf, Qin, Quinn, and Rho8. It also has the FlowAccumulationFullWorkflow tool, which combines all the necessary pre-processing steps into a single tool. However, the documentation does not mention any algorithm specifically:

Resolves all of the depressions in a DEM, outputting a breached DEM, an aspect-aligned non-divergent flow pointer, and a flow accumulation raster.

So, I wonder: which flow accumulation algorithm is executed by the FlowAccumulationFullWorkflow tool in Whitebox?

when in doubt go and look at the source code

As Ian suggested, checking the source code:

NOTES: This tool provides a full workflow D8 flow operation. This includes removing depressions, calculating
the D8 pointer raster and finally the D8 flow accumulation operation.

So D8 is. You can check it in line 8
